# Jquery create array from text "2-6" like [2,3,4,5,6]

Tags: jquery

So the title says pretty much for itself.
For example, I have div like this:

```
<div class="somediv">2009-2014</div>
```

What's the way to create array within such conditions? 
Get few vars, substract and slice to get first and last value, but how to insert this in array then, so it could make range of numbers from first to last?

div will always contain years, so substract or slice should do the work to get values. I just don't know how could I make array with range of given numbers later.

Comment: `function range(min, max) { var a = []; for(var i = min; i <= max; i++) { a.push(i); } return a; }`?

Comment: really question title and in the question area different and unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `map` and split should do the trick:

```
$(".somediv").map(function() {
    var split =  $(this).text().split("-");
    var min = parseInt(split[0], 10), max = parseInt(split[1], 10);
    var arr = [];
    for(var i=min; i<=max; i++) arr.push(i);
    return arr;
});
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/3FFa7/)

Should you have multiple `.somediv` elements, you could also sort them to get a sorted, concatenated array:

```
console.log($(".somediv").map(function() {
    var split =  $(this).text().split("-");
    var min = parseInt(split[0], 10), max = parseInt(split[1], 10);
    var arr = [];
    for(var i=min; i<=max; i++) arr.push(i);
    return arr;
}).sort().get());
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/r3j8B/)

Answer (score 0):

The following should do it:

```
function extractYears(selector) {
    var text = $(selector).text();
    return text.split(/[^\d]+/).map(function (yearText) {
        return parseInt(yearText);
    });
}

function makeRange(min, max) {
    var a = [];
    for (var i = min; i <= max; ++i) {
        a.push(i);
    }
    return a;
}

var range = makeRange.apply(null, extractYears('.somediv'));
```